# How do I change the ownership of /cygdrive/c

Tags: cygwin

I need to create a file in /cygdrive/c but that folder is owned by "NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller". All the posts I've seen say to right-click on the folder in Windows and change the ownership. But I can't find /cygdrive/c in
Windows. And I can't change the ownership in Cygwin.

I've tried changing the permissions in cygwin:
$ /cygdrive
$ chmod 777 c
chmod: changing permissions of 'c': Permission denied

I've tried vi /cygdrive/c/.netrc
but when I save I get:
".netrc" E212: Can't open file for writing

Comment: Have you tried opening an Adminstrator command window and doing a `mkdir c:\mydir`. Then change owner using `takeown /f c:\mydir` in an non-admin command window. This is safer than trying to change ownership of the C: drive.

Comment: That would work, but I stated I don't know how to find /cygdrive/c when I'm under windows. I actually am the owner of the C: drive, but not /cygdrive/c under Cygwin. Which is strange because I thought they were the same drive.

Comment: `/cygdrive/c` IS `C:\\`.

Comment: C:\ has one owner and /cygdrive/c has a different owner. My original problem was that I was trying to create a file in /cygdrive/c and it wouldn't let me. Hence the need to change ownership. However, they are the same place, so I just went to Windows and placed the file in C:\. Now I can get to the file in /cygdrive/c. So this does resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

/cygdrive/c IS `C:\`. by Doug Henderson does resolve my issue.

C:\ has one owner and /cygdrive/c has a different owner. My original problem was that I was trying to create a file in /cygdrive/c and it wouldn't let me. Hence the need to change ownership. However, they are the same place, so I just went to Windows and placed the file in C:. Now I can get to the file in /cygdrive/c. So this does resolve my problem.